# \subsubsubsection instead of \paragraph in LaTeX export with header levels and section numbering > 3

Tags: org-export, latex-header

How should I get a proper numbered header `\subsubsubsection{The Header}` instead of a numbered paragraph `\paragraph{The Header}` when exporting to LaTeX with header levels of more than 3?

Having this in my preamble:

```latex
% Set default Counter Depth 
\\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} 
\\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

And this in my Org file:

```org
#+OPTIONS: H:5 num:t
```

Produces numbered paragraphs instead of proper headings at the fourth level and above.

The answer given over [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-10/msg00192.html) did not solve the problem.

---

## Sample Data:

```org
#+OPTIONS: H:5

* Section
some text
** Subsection
some text
*** Subsubsection
some text
**** Subsubsubsection
some text
```

[image]

Comment: Standard LaTeX stops at subsubsection. Are you using a package that defines more sectioning?

Comment: I am using `titlesec` to create more sectioning. (Max. 5 levels)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is my solution to the problem.

Below is part of the `org-latex-classes` code:

```latex
\\usepackage{titlesec}
\\usepackage{titling}
\\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.

% Set Header and Numbering Depth
\\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

% Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.
\\titleformat*{\\section}{\\fontsize{20}{22}\\bfseries\\sffamily}
\\titleformat*{\\subsection}{\\fontsize{18}{20}\\bfseries\\sffamily}
\\titleformat*{\\subsubsection}{\\fontsize{16}{18}\\bfseries\\sffamily} 

% The `titlesec` package is used over here to make use of `\\paragraph` and `\\subparagraph` as headings. Up to five levels of headings can be implemented this way. 
\\titleformat{\\paragraph}
    {\\fontsize{14}{16}\\bfseries\\sffamily}{\\theparagraph}{1em}{} 
% New line after heading. (`\\paragraph` and `\\subparagraph` would not automatically generate a new line after the heading text. )
\\titlespacing*{\\paragraph}{\\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.75ex plus .1ex}

\\titleformat{\\subparagraph}
    {\\fontsize{12}{14}\\bfseries\\sffamily}{\\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
\\titlespacing*{\\subparagraph}{\\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.75ex plus .1ex}
```

This lies right at the end of `org-latex-classes` to implement all 5 levels of subheadings:

```el
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")
```

Comment: Thanks, from a newbie. In which class will each heading and subheading  be formatted into?

Comment: The above code is for articles.